# How do I hide a span element based on a Javascript variable? Angular material

Tags: javascript, angular-material

I have a messaging app using Angular Material. I'd like the program to check when the amount of unread messages equals 0, to hide a span element that shows the number of unread messages.

topbar.html:

`<span class="button_badge" id="button_badge">{{notifications}}</span>`

the `{{notifications}}` variable comes from a JavaScript controller. How can I make the program check when notifications == 0 to hide the element?

Comment: You can use ng-hide="notifications== 0" I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this with AngularJs.

1. Use ng-hide or ng-show : 
   `<span class="button_badge" id="button_badge" ng-hide="notifications == 0">{{notifications}}</span>`
2. Use ng-if : `<span class="button_badge" id="button_badge" ng-if="notifications != 0">{{notifications}}</span>`

Hope this helps you!